# Multidimensional array outputs zero between odd number array

Tags: java

I have this program:

```
class PrintOdd {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num = 1;
        int product = 1;
        int oddArray[][] = new int[10][7];

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {

                if ((num < 100) && (num % 2 != 0)) {
                    oddArray[i][j] = num;
                    num++;
                } else {
                    num++;
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
                System.out.print(oddArray[i][j] + "\t ");
            }
            System.out.print("\n ");
        }
    }
}
```

and result:

```
 1   0   3   0   5   0   7   
 0   9   0   11  0   13  0   
 15  0   17  0   19  0   21  
 0   23  0   25  0   27  0   
 29  0   31  0   33  0   35  
 0   37  0   39  0   41  0   
 43  0   45  0   47  0   49  
 0   51  0   53  0   55  0   
 57  0   59  0   61  0   63  
 0   65  0   67  0   69  0
```

This code prints odd numbers between 0 and 99 but as from the above output it prints zero between the odd numbers. Can anyone tell me where the zero's come from because i do not understand. This code prints odd numbers between 0 and 99 but as from the above output it prints zero between the odd numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the test `( num % 2 !=0)`, which is only true if num is odd, you are only assigning values to the odd positions in your array. The rest is not touched and contains the initial value, which is set to 0 when the array is created.

If what you want is an array with only odd numbers, try this: increment num with 2 at a time (so you skip all even numbers). You won't need to test for odd-ness anymore and you can drop the corresponding else clause. You'll also need an array that's only half the size.

So:

```
 for(int j=0; j<7; j++){

     if(num < 100){
         oddArray[i][j]= num;
         num+=2;
     }
 }
```

A final comment: you may want to look into the `break` statement to jump out of the loop when `num` reaches 100. With your current code, the loop continues until the end without doing anything.

Comment: Thanks so what can i do to prevent this?

Comment: That depends. What do you want the code to do? And why did you write the if/else statement this way?

Comment: Using num+=2 is the simplest, Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The array will be initialized with all zeroes, and you are only filling half of the slots. For every `j` where `num` is even, the array will still contain a zero on that slot.

Answer (score 0):

Your error that you increment i,j in all cases (odd/even) number, Try this code:

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
 for(int j=0; j<7; j++){
   if((num < 100) &&( num % 2 !=0) ){
     oddArray[i][j]= num;
     num++;
    }else{
      num++;
      j--;
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: I have to say that changing the value of the loop variable `j` is something I wouldn't do. In my opinion that's a bad practice and confusing for new programmers. Normally it indicates that the loop itself is implemented incorrectly. See my answer for a different way to solve this.